# Jquery hide() show() not working

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

I hope i'm posting on the right place because I dont want to create another topic with the same issue... My code works on jsfiddle but does not on my site... dont know why...

Working Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcDtr/703/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.resp").hide();
    $("input[name$='resp']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.resp").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    });
});
```

The whole page with the same code (not working): [Page](http://jsfiddle.net/a0x29kLr/2/)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.resp").hide();
    $("input[name$='resp']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.resp").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a0x29kLr/3/  .. be sure to include jquery

Comment: but it's there: <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>